Combining WhatsApp chat backups - main phone + temporary phone
My phone was in repair for a few days so I used a temporary one, and set up WhatsApp. Only, I didn't restore the backup then and there on the temp phone.
Now I have my main phone back, and I want to combine the messages I sent and received for the few days on the temp phone, with the much larger backup of historical ones on the main phone.
Is there a way I can do this?
My initial idea was to restore the original backup on my newly returned main phone (which has been wiped), then create a new backup on the temp phone, then go back to main phone and restore backup again. Will that combine the two, or will it erase all the old data and keep only the few days I gathered with the temp?

AFAIK not possible//In the past it was possible to merge both Whatsapp databases if your device is rooted but I believe that's also not possible now

Unanswered question on same lines here //IMO Duplicate
